# CakePHP - PHPUNIT - Tables getting deleted when we run test.php

Tags: cakephp, testing, phpunit

I'm a newbie to PHPUnit testing. I have successfully installed PHPUnit and I am able to run it. I have a new database with some records. Whenever I run the test cases, the tables are getting deleted and I'm getting Database error. Please help...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, and expected behaviour.

You should create a second database in order to run your tests. In your `app/Config/database.php` you will see a `$test` database configuration.

This is the configuration that will used by your tests. [There is a warning in the book about this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#test-database-setup).

Comment: Yes... I have a separate database only for testing. But I want to  test the form inputs...How to write test cases for it...

Comment: That's a totally different question. You'll want to learn about Functional Testing and probably Selenium.